# I want to create batch script to start the services which are down and startup type is automatic

Tags: batch-file

I am able to pull the services which are down and list them in a file with the below code but need help to design the script which can check down services and if startup type is Automatic just start them.

```
@echo off 

wmic service where started=false get name >> stoppedservices.txt

echo "The program has completed"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sc` command in the for loop to complete your script:

```
@echo off 
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in ('wmic service where started^=false get name') do (
    for /f "tokens=3" %%t in ('sc qc %%s ^|findstr /c:"START_TYPE"') do (
        if "%%t"=="2" net start %%s
    )
)
echo "The program has completed"
pause>nul
```

If desired, you can use `sc start` instead of `net start`.

`net start` will return success message after the startup task is completed while `sc start` will return message as it is processing service startup. If you are a person who likes to see the process completed step by step, `net start` would be better choice for you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and do it all using the same WMIC command.

```bat
WMIC Service Where "StartMode='Auto' And Started='False'" Call StartService
```

Just bear in mind that, some services may be either delayed auto starting or pending and this does not take such information into account.

Comment: Thanks, its working but there are few services like "iClarityQoSService, isaHelperSvc and O2FLASH" which are not starting even after being automatic.